# Single Page App but with dynamically rendered index.html

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, expo, single-page-application

The app that I am building uses Expo + React Native. It works like this: our clients get their own URL, but essentially, it's the same app. So, if they want to add Google Analytics to track conversions, I would have to add all their tags to the same index.html file, which is not ideal.

One way I can think of is to combine Next.js with Expo, but it seems like overkill for this simple goal, but it does add more flexibility and potential to our app. Does anyone have a good idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option, in my opinion, is to use [React Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet). It gives the option to add different types of meta-tags to different pages, and it is useful if you have dynamic data.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
 
class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="https://google.com" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```